# How does the addition of Chicory affect coffee?

Tags: coffee

Chicory is a common additive in Indian Coffee. A quick search in wikipedia reveals that it is usually 20-30% in coffee powder. 
Can coffee be made solely out of chicory? Does the chicory root contain caffeine or just the flavor profile of coffee?

Comment: This answer to a previous question is related: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/9163/1672

Comment: There is coffee made solely of chicory, yes - or at least without real coffee, it could contain some other additives. Popular brands are Inka and Caro.

Comment: civil war soldiers in america used to use chicory in the field because coffee was scarce or too expensive.

Comment: Also dandelion makes a similar coffee substitute

Answer (score 9):

Roasted chicory root (which is what you are adding to coffee) contains no caffeine.

What chicory does is add a nice, roasted flavor to coffee, which is desireable either for cultural reasons, or to offset the bitter flavor of over-roasted low-grade coffee beans.  Originally, it was also added because it was much, much cheaper than coffee.  That's not true anymore, even in India as far as I know.

Proper New Orleans or Vietnamese coffee also contains a lot of chicory.

Answer (score 1):

Chicory has no caffeine, hence it reduces the caffeine content in brewed coffee. It also thickens the brew.